# Difficult, possibly symmetric, integral

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

I went to a competition 2 weeks ago and it was time to review. This integral keeps bugging me $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2017x}-e^x}{x(e^{2017x}+1)(e^x+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ This practically screams symmetry at me and I can't figure out how to apply it. I started with a u-sub $u=e^x$ but that $x$ term on the bottom creates a problematic $\ln x$. I tried to split it at 0 and then make the substitution $x=\frac{1}{u}$ but again not prosperous. **Edit** In response to Justin's comment, the integral can now be split up into $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(e^x+1)}-\frac{1}{x(e^{2017x}+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ and I don't know what to do here either.

Comment: This function is not continuous  ?!

Comment: Add zero ($1-1$) to the numerator then cancel into two nicer integrals

Comment: The singularity at $x=0$ is removable, since $e^{2017x}-e^x = 2016x+o(x)$ near $x=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @Justin's suggestion, we find the general result that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{ e^{ax}-e^{bx} }{(e^{ax}+1)(e^{bx}+1)} \frac{dx}{x} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{e^{bx}+1} - \frac{1}{e^{ax}+1} \right) \frac{dx}{x}. $$
Any seasoned integrator will roll their eyes at this point, bang it on the head with [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html), and go about their business. Slightly more care than usual is required here, because the integral is over the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, rather than just the positive part, so let's go carefully. The integrand can be written as
$$ \left( \frac{1}{e^{bx}+1} - \frac{1}{e^{ax}+1} \right) \frac{1}{x} = \int_b^a \frac{e^{tx}}{(e^{tx}+1)^2} \, dt, $$
and thankfully the integrand of this is positive, so we can use Tonelli's theorem to change the order of integration,
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_b^a \frac{e^{tx}}{(e^{tx}+1)^2} \, dt \, dx = \int_b^a \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{tx}}{(e^{tx}+1)^2} \, dx \, dt $$
The inner integral is thankfully quite straightforward: it has antiderivative
$$ -\frac{1}{t} \frac{1}{e^{tx}+1}, $$
and evaluating at $\pm \infty$, only $-\infty$ contributes and we are left with
$$ \int_b^a \frac{dt}{t} = \log{(a/b)}. $$
In our case $a=2017$ and $b=1$, so the answer is $\log{2017}$ (of course!).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will definitely be using that later. Beautiful solution by the way

Comment: The same idea can be used to prove the Frullani integral's value: $$\frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x} = \int_b^a f'(tx) \, dt$$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may recall that, for $a>0$ and $s>-1$,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s}}{e^{ax}+1}\:dx=\left(1-2^{-s} \right) a^{-s-1} \zeta (s+1) \Gamma (s+1)
$$ giving, for $b>0$,
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x(e^{ax}+1)(e^{bx}+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\\\\&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x(e^{ax}+1)(e^{bx}+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\\\\&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{x}\left(\frac{1}{e^{bx}+1}-\frac{1}{e^{ax}+1} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x
\\\\&=2\lim_{s \to -1^+}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^s}{e^{bx}+1}-\frac{x^s}{e^{ax}+1} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x
\\\\&=2\lim_{s \to -1^+}\left[(b^{-s-1}-a^{-s-1})\left(1-2^{-s}\right) \zeta (s+1) \Gamma (s+1) \right]
\\\\&=\log \frac ba.
\end{align}
$$